# 'tensorflow.keras.models.load_model' results in "ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure."

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

After I save a model and load it, I get "ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure."

This is the code to reproduce the error

```
!pip install transformers --q
%tensorflow_version 2.x

from transformers import TFBertModel, AutoModel
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense,
                                     Dropout)

class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data

        batch_label = tf.reshape(y, (tf.size(y)/2, 2), name=None)

        rs = tf.ragged.stack(x, axis=0)
        reg = rs.to_tensor()
        batch_input = tf.reshape(reg, (tf.shape(reg)[0]*tf.shape(reg)[1], tf.shape(reg)[2]))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(batch_input, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(batch_label, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

def get_model(drop_out):
    sciBert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased', from_pt=True)

    # posFinal = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputP') 
    # negFinal = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputN') 
    allFinal = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputN') 

    '''Should posFinal and negFinal be concatenated, so there's only one call to sciBert'''
    # posBertOut = sciBert(posFinal)
    # negBertOut = sciBert(negFinal)
    allBertOut = sciBert(allFinal)

    # embedding of size 768*3
    allPoolConcat = tf.concat([
                    allBertOut[1], #output of ff layer after last hidden state since it seems to be untrained in roberta
                    tf.reduce_mean(allBertOut[0][:, 1:-1], axis=1), # pooled except CLS and SEP
                    # tf.math.reduce_max(allBertOut[0][:, 1:-1], axis=1),
                    allBertOut[0][:, -1] # sep, get from hidden state 
                    ],axis=1) 

    allPoolConcat = Dropout(drop_out)(allPoolConcat)
    classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='tanh', name='qff')

    allScores = classifier(allPoolConcat) 

    model = CustomModel(inputs=allFinal, outputs=allScores)
    return model

config = {
  'drop_out':0.2
}

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model = get_model(**config)
model.compile(loss=loss_fn,
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5))

model.save('modelSave')
loadedModel = tf.keras.models.load_model('modelSave')
```

And this is the full error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in assert_same_structure(nest1, nest2, check_types, expand_composites)
    377     _pywrap_utils.AssertSameStructure(nest1, nest2, check_types,
--> 378                                       expand_composites)
    379   except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:

ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=dict str={'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}

Second structure: type=TensorSpec str=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')

More specifically: Substructure "type=dict str={'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}" is a sequence, while substructure "type=TensorSpec str=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')" is not

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
11 frames
<ipython-input-8-4076a08f1890> in <module>()
----> 1 loadedModel = tf.keras.models.load_model('modelSave')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    188     if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):
    189       loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
--> 190       return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
    191 
    192   raise IOError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile)
    114   # TODO(kathywu): Add saving/loading of optimizer, compiled losses and metrics.
    115   # TODO(kathywu): Add code to load from objects that contain all endpoints
--> 116   model = tf_load.load_internal(path, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
    117 
    118   # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, loader_cls)
    602       loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto,
    603                           saved_model_proto,
--> 604                           export_dir)
    605       root = loader.get(0)
    606       if isinstance(loader, Loader):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    186     self._models_to_reconstruct = []
    187 
--> 188     super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    189 
    190     # Now that the node object has been fully loaded, and the checkpoint has

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir)
    121       self._concrete_functions[name] = _WrapperFunction(concrete_function)
    122 
--> 123     self._load_all()
    124     self._restore_checkpoint()
    125 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _load_all(self)
    213 
    214     # Finish setting up layers and models. See function docstring for more info.
--> 215     self._finalize_objects()
    216 
    217   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _finalize_objects(self)
    504         layers_revived_from_saved_model.append(node)
    505 
--> 506     _finalize_saved_model_layers(layers_revived_from_saved_model)
    507     _finalize_config_layers(layers_revived_from_config)
    508 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _finalize_saved_model_layers(layers)
    675       call_fn = _get_keras_attr(layer).call_and_return_conditional_losses
    676       if call_fn.input_signature is None:
--> 677         inputs = infer_inputs_from_restored_call_function(call_fn)
    678       else:
    679         inputs = call_fn.input_signature[0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in infer_inputs_from_restored_call_function(fn)
    919   for concrete in fn.concrete_functions[1:]:
    920     spec2 = concrete.structured_input_signature[0][0]
--> 921     spec = nest.map_structure(common_spec, spec, spec2)
    922   return spec
    923 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    609   for other in structure[1:]:
    610     assert_same_structure(structure[0], other, check_types=check_types,
--> 611                           expand_composites=expand_composites)
    612 
    613   flat_structure = [flatten(s, expand_composites) for s in structure]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in assert_same_structure(nest1, nest2, check_types, expand_composites)
    383                   "Entire first structure:\n%s\n"
    384                   "Entire second structure:\n%s"
--> 385                   % (str(e), str1, str2))
    386 
    387 

ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=dict str={'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}

Second structure: type=TensorSpec str=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')

More specifically: Substructure "type=dict str={'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}" is a sequence, while substructure "type=TensorSpec str=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')" is not
Entire first structure:
{'input_ids': .}
Entire second structure:
.
```

Comment: Try changing `allBertOut = sciBert(allFinal)` to `allBertOut = sciBert.bert(allFinal)` as reported here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3627#issuecomment-646390974